# Python: For a 2D array, sum the 2nd col of the non-unique elements in first col?

Tags: python, numpy

Hi Please could you help me with this problem.

I have a sorted 2D numpy array with some repeated elements in the first col, I would like to create a new sorted array where the 2nd column has summed the repeated elements.

E.g. I have a 2 by 4 array:

```
y = np.array(([14.0, 100], [15.0, 130], [15.0, -90], [16.0, 60]))
```

I want the following 2 by 3 array:

```
z = np.array(([14.0, 100], [15.0, 40], [16.0, 60]))
```

I'm looking at reduce/map/lambda but haven't got it to work yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
sums=[np.sum(y[:,1],where=y[:,0]==a) for a in np.unique(y[:,0])]
counts=np.stack([np.unique(y[:,0]),sums],axis=1)
```

This gives the following result:

```
[[ 14. 100.][ 15.  40.][ 16.  60.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

With `np.unique` + `np.split`:

```
u, idx = np.unique(Y[:, 0], return_index=True)
Z = np.column_stack([u, [a.sum() for a in np.split(Y[:,1], idx)[1:]]])
```

---

```
array([[ 14., 100.],
       [ 15.,  40.],
       [ 16.,  60.]])
```